# TestComplete Recorder doesn't recognize popups elements

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, automation, testcomplete

I'm trying to record a test using TestComplete 10.
The application I test contains popups. The popup contains clickable buttons and links.
The problem is that when executing the recorded test- TestComplete does not recognize the popup itself and all the elements in the popup.
TestComplete waits for the popup element and then the test fails.

The application bases on WPF on Windows OS.

I'll be glad for some help regards this issue.
There is a way to pass this, any extension needed?

Comment: Contact the SmartBear Customer Care team. They are very good at helping with such issues:
http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using TC10, I would always suggest updating to the newest version 12.5!

Beyond that, it could be a couple of different things, but first you should run through this requirements link to determine whether or not TC can see your application.
 https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/desktop/wpf/requirements.html You could also take a look at this other link https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/desktop/wpf/index.html and see if it helps.  Both links are for TC12.5, but some of these functionalities might still be available in your version.

Please let me know if you need some more assistance.